# plugin on same page error wen we click on

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

I create a plugin in which a form have a two button, first button goes to next page and second button goes to same page. When I come on same page it is showing an error :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_shortcode() in C:\wamp\www\sanyam\wp-content\plugins\a.php on line 31
```

`none-aa.php` is a different page on action.

Comment: <?php
/*
* Plugin Name:sanyam

function form_creation()
{
?>
<form name = "f1" method = "post" action = "http://localhost/sanyam/wp-content/plugins/aa.php"> 
 First: <input type="text" name="first"><br>
 date: <input type="date" name="last"><br>
<input type='submit' value='Open default action file'> 
<input type='submit' value='Open test6.html' onclick="f1.action='http://localhost/sanyam/wp-content/plugins/a.php'; return true;">
 </form>
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['first']))
 {
  $a = $_POST['first'];
  $b = $_POST['last'];
 }
  echo $a;
  echo $b;
 
}
add_shortcode('two', 'form_creation');
?>

Comment: Please do not add your codes in the comment instead edit your question and add the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error says, they you call undefined function add_shortcode().
Post some code to better identify problem.

Comment: <?php
/*
* Plugin Name: sanyam

function form_creation()
{
?>
<form name = "f1" method = "post" action = "http://localhost/sanyam/wp-content/plugins/aa.php"> 
 First: <input type="text" name="first"><br>
 date: <input type="date" name="last"><br>
<input type='submit' value='Open default action file'> 
<input type='submit' value='Open test6.html' onclick="f1.action='http://localhost/sanyam/wp-content/plugins/a.php'; return true;">
 </form>
 <?php
 if (isset($_POST['first']))
 {
  $a = $_POST['first'];
  $b = $_POST['last'];
 }
  echo $a;
  echo $b;
}
add_shortcode('two', 'form_creation');
?>